# Symlinking a .desktop files compresses the file

Tags: symlink, compression

I am trying to install an application needed for my university. Whenever I am trying to symlink the .desktop file from original folder, it somehow compresses it and then puts it in the .local/share/applications file, where I want to put the .desktop. How do I know it is compressed? It's red in the terminal.

Here is a picture with it in the origin folder:
[image: zoteroPicture]

Here is a picture with it in the destination (.local/share/applications) folder: [image: zoteroPictureRed]

The problem is that I cannot open the app from the menu of the OS. The file does not appear in the menu.

Comment: A red listing also indicates a symlink which points to a non-existing file. Can you add the output of `ls -l zotero.desktop` (the link, not the target)? By the way nice idea to use zotero for managing your references.

Comment: Thank you very much Hermann! Since I had to get it up running asap, i just used my w11 vm, but will do this in a few hours. Even though it's working, maybe other people will find it useful. As I said, I will install it in a couple of hours and will let you know. Just to be sure it's clear to me, should i `ls -l zotero.desktop` in the origin folder?

Comment: I guess `ls -l ~/.local/share/applications/zotero.desktop` will produce interesting output.

Comment: @Hermann yup, there you go `lrwxrwxrwx 1 knr knr 14 Feb 28 10:08 /home/knr/.local/share/applications/zotero.desktop -> zotero.desktop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the red colour indicates a damaged symlink. Symbolic links can work with arbitrary paths – relative as well as absolute. In this particular case, the symlink `zotero.desktop -> zotero.desktop` points to itself. This is considered invalid. You should delete the symlink and re-create it. If working on the command-line is too cumbersome, I can recommend using your graphical file-manager for the task. Many include an appropriate feature (for example in thunar it is drag and drop with the right mouse button).